# Copy Namespace with new name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

What is the best way to copy a namespace in Visual Studio?

What I mean by that would be to take a folder in the Solution Explorer say 'Namespace1', and copy it, but in the process rename namespace in the folder's files to 'Namespace2'.

The key being to only update references and usings inside the new copied folder.

What I am doing now is Drag and drop copying the folder in solution explorer, excluding the original from Project, changing the namespace on one file then using the drop down option to "rename Namespace1 to Namespace2".  Problem is that updates my external references to the copy and is annoying to re-import the original after excluding it.

Comment: Replace In Files might work - IF your namespace is unique enough it doesn't collide with too much else to be a bother. Depending on the number of files and uses, there's probably not much to gain.

Comment: It sounds like it's going to be a manual process (either do change it or to verify the change) no matter what you do.  Out of curiosity, what are you achieving by duplicating all of this code?  Why do you need this?

Comment: There can be a few reasons, often it is to try changes out and retain the possibility to revert (without copying entire project), or to altogether branch functionality on an existing control.

Comment: @jimmyjambles You should be using source control for that.

Comment: Yes, it is rather dangerous. But possibly faster and with certain coding styles it could work very well so I mentioned it in a comment (I don't know the code you have). But for your use case, you should really be using version control as @cadrell0 mentions and not copying or renaming anything.

Comment: @cadrell0 agreed, in this case it is for smaller projects that arent source controlled

Comment: @jimmyjambles If you have a source control system set up, there is no reason to not put every single project in it.